# javascript get specified amount of array when a function is invoked using slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Let's say I have 15 objects in an array.
I am showing only 5 of them on the browser like this.

```
const array1 = Array.slice(0,4)
```

Also, I have a function which will be invoked when a user scrolls down.
and I would like show another 5 of them per a scroll.

```
array1.concat(Array.slice(5,9))
```

However, there is still other objects left in the array. `Array.slice(10, ~)`

How can I repeat this one?

I am using React and [react-infinite-scroll-component](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/react-infinite-scroll-component)

[This example](https://codesandbox.io/s/439v8rmqm0) might help you to understand my question. only difference is the example creates array from 0 and I already have 15 objects in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep track of where you are using a variable, for instance to start with:

```
let start = 0;
```

then, when you want to show the next five:

```
if (start < originalArray.length) {
    let end = Math.min(start + 5, originalArray.length) {
        if (end > start) {
            array1  = array1.concat(originalArray.slice(start, end));
            // Presumably a `setState` call here using `array1`
            start = end;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! that works awesome! I don't know who voted down :/